# Patch PHP script in a KSplice-like fashion

Tags: php, runtime, dynamic, patch

This is mostly an **experiment**, but I do think it does have some practical uses.

The idea is to be able to patch a PHP script at runtime without have to reload the request.

For example, let's say I wrote a WebSocket server in PHP, and this server is running the following class...

```
class MyServerApp extends WebSocketServerApp {
    protected $clients = array();

    public function onConnect($client){
        $this->clients[$client->getId()] = $client;
    }

    public function onDisconnect($client){
        unset($this->clients[$client->getId()]);
    }

    public function onData($client, $data){
        $client->send($data); // perform echo functionality
    }

}
```

Basically, the server creates a single instance of `MyServerApp` class and calls it appropriately. The above app is an echo server; it responds to all client request with exactly what they asked for.

Now let's say I modified the server source code and want to keep the existing server running, but change behaviour (so as to not loose the existing clients). The app server conveniently has an `onTick()` event, which we can use to check changes to the source code:

```
class MyServerApp extends WebSocketServerApp {
    // the existing code from above goes here

    /**
     * @var integer Timestamp of when the server was last patched.
     */
    public $last_patch = 0;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->last_patch = time();
    }

    public function onTick(){
        if($this->last_patch < filemtime(__FILE__)){
            // include __FILE__;
        }
    }
}
```

The patching check will probably work nicely, **but the actual patching method won't (it is currently commented, by the way).**
The main reason is that the server class has already been defined.

So how would you do the actual patching? Somehow overwrite functions, or classes?

### Possible Solutions

- Use a better suited language (such as js/node.js) which allows overwriting (@teresko)
- Use classkit (and/or alternatives) to overwrite PHP functions/classes (@MatějZábský)
- Offload server logic to anonymous functions and simply overwrite such functions*
- Rename duped classes and load them normally (definitely leaks memory though) (@chris)

[*] `server.php` would look like:

```
$server['onData'] = function(){ /* new function body */ };
```

### Notes

On the other hand, this architecture poses some issues that really need to be tended to:

- permanent damage to the running server
- memory leaks (some resources *will* get leaked, probably including functions)

  - (does PHP have a GC for functions?)

Comment: So what is the question? I don't see any question marks in there :)

Comment: @MatějZábský Well, reading every word I wrote, you couldn't have missed the question the situation poses, but I edited it in the name of clarity anyway :) Of course I should have been more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to have a look at [classkit](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.classkit.php) (its function [classkit_method_redefine](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.classkit-method-redefine.php) and [classkit_import](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.classkit-import.php) in particular).

But that's really horrible way to go. Are you sure you can't afford to have a millisecond down-time while restarting the script (as everyone does)?

This may also not be sustainable in long term (I wouldn't be surprised if the overwritten method was just leaked). Also, I'm not sure if the tick callback is really built for use on production server (it may have some performance overhead).

EDIT:

Sadly, there is rather limited number of articles about PHP's garbage collector. [Here](http://www.tuxradar.com/practicalphp/18/1/10) is one (it is a part of series on performance optimizations in PHP), but it doesn't go into details on how functions or types are treated.

From my experience, PHP scripts running continuously for days need to be restarted every few days (I use Cron-job which tries to start the script every few minutes along with a lock file), because after that, the script becomes less and less stable.

Comment: I agree, classkit and similar alternatives aren't the good way to go. The problem with downtime is that I loose connection to everyone. What I'm asking for is mostly brain-storming, as I said, this is just an experiment mostly.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without any extension ... but the sollution is not just dirty ... it is the Antichrist of code!

If you use eval within a method the evaluated  code may use $this to access private and protected properties and methods!

You can store the source code in any type of file or database and whenever the source is updated you can load the updated source code into a string and eval it in your method.

If you want to be able to use the classs as ordinary class or as dynamic source class things get a little complicated:

1. create the server class
2. create an child class that overrides all methods (using eval)
3. check for updates.
4. if the file is updated use the tokenizer function to scan the source for function definitions (a function token [-> whitespace | comments ]-> a string token with the right function name  -> not '{' -> '{')
5. concat all tokens until  you have as many closing as opening curly brakets.
6. use the resulting string tokens in your evaling methods.

And no this is not sparta .... it is madness.

If you want to learn more about  the structure of PHP files go ahead.

But **never ever** use this in a productive environment!!!!!!!

Comment: Eval? :D Didn't quite expect that.

Comment: @ChristianSciberras it is a modified version of one of my experiments. If you really want to you can us his to implement traits in PHP 5.3. The fake trait is just an interface that defines a constant string with the source code for every method. And no I do not use it in productive code. And yes you CAN us eval together with  __call and a reflection class to "steal" implementations from other classes ^^

Answer (score 0):

I think you would need to use an extension like runkit if you wanted to redefine a class. But, you could also just give the new class some form of serial name like MyClassVersion56. Use a factory to instantitate the class, and the factory knows the name of the most recent class because you set a variable somewhere. You could even str_replace the source code to make the serial naming automatic.

keep an eye on memory usage if you run php scripts for long periods of time...

there's ways to define program behavior dynamically, but at some point you start to recreate a programming language, when you're already using a dynamic one like php. But if the variations in behavior are of limited scope, consider it over dynamic code execution like what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

The only nice way I can think of is splitting up the work into two scripts:
One script holds the connections and one does the actual work.

The connction scrpts writtes the request data into a database or memcache driven "job pool", and looks for results that it can return in the "result pool".

The work script takes jobs from the pool, processes them, and puts the results in the "result pool".

This way you can edit your logic in the work script and restart it without loosing your connections.

I do not think that this is a good way to implement a server, but the choice is up to you.